# Function in Informix to return number of minutes between two Datetimes

Tags: sql, informix

Here's what I have for now (it doesn't work):

```
CREATE FUNCTION DIFFERENCE_IN_MINUTES(start DATETIME, end DATETIME)
RETURNING ((start - end)::interval minute(8) to minute)::char(10)::int8;
```

I want to be able to use it like this: `where DIFFERENCE_IN_MINUTES(startTime, endTime) > 100` for example. What is the correct way to accomplish that? I'm using Informix 11.70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you've discovered the [difficulty](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1605282) of converting `INTERVAL` values to `INTEGER`, but the problem in your code is syntactical, I think. The use of the reserved words `START` and `END` may be complicating things, too.

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DIFFERENCE_IN_MINUTES(a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND,
                                      b DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND)
        RETURNING INT8;
    RETURN ((b - a)::INTERVAL MINUTE(8) TO MINUTE)::CHAR(10)::INT8;
END FUNCTION;
```

I tested that using the function as a predicate, and it seems to work fine.